# Checking if data exists in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 database tables _USERS and _NODES I would like to check _USERS and make sure every user has a record in _NODES.

At the moment i simply loop the _USERS table and insert a record into _NODES if it doesn't exist.

As I get more users this loop takes longer.... How can i check _USERS and insert any missing user ID's into _NODES without having to loop the records in _USERS...

```
function blc_adm_sync(){
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix."users";
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table");
foreach($result as $mb8wp_config){

    $usrnode = getUNode($mb8wp_config->ID);

}
echo "All done, refresh your page.";

wp_die();   
}
```

This function simply loops the _USERS table and adds a record to _NODES if the user doesn't have a record in there already.

Comment: Use a negative left join? E.g. `SELECT * FROM \`_USERS\` u LEFT JOIN \`_NODES\` n ON n.user_id = u.id WHERE n.id IS NULL`, or something.

Comment: How about when you create or delete a user, you just add a insert, delete trigger, triggers usually remove the need of running many unnecessary queries.

Comment: Disagree about the triggers, but completely agree with the "do it when you add / delete the user in the first place!" bit rather than hacking it on later.

Comment: Thanks Guys LEFT JOIN done the trick...

Comment: why is it when i use SELECT * FROM wpdev_users u LEFT JOIN wpdev_mb8wp_node_users n ON n.wpuid = u.ID WHERE n.wpuid IS NULL i no longer get the ID in the results its just blank now!

Answer (score 0):

This worked a treat...

```
SELECT * FROM mbc1co_users u LEFT JOIN mbc1co_mb8wp_node_users n ON n.wpuid = u.ID WHERE n.wpuid IS NULL
```

Comment: Why is it when i use SELECT * FROM wpdev_users u LEFT JOIN wpdev_mb8wp_node_users n ON n.wpuid = u.ID WHERE n.wpuid IS NULL it no longer gives me the ID in the results?